# how do I add template conditions in the ListView class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a ListView class in views.py, I want to add a condition if the authenticated user displays another template

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .views import (
    PostListView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

## Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
)
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'page/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 7
```

i want to add

```
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            template_name = 'page/index.html'
        else:
            template_name = 'page/home.html'
```

Django 2.2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [**`get_template_names`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names):

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return ['page/index.html']
        else:
            return ['page/home.html']
```

As the documentation says, this function:

> Returns a **list of template names** to search for when rendering the template. The **first template that is found will be used**.
>
> If `template_name` is specified, the default implementation will return a list containing `template_name` (if it is specified).

That being said, if you do not plan to render the list on your `home.html` page, it might be better to perform a *redirect* to another page, instead of just rendering a page. Otherwise, if you later want to add more content to your `home.html` page, you will each time need to update all the views that render this.

The [basic implementation [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L140) in the [**`TemplateResponseMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#templateresponsemixin) is thus:

> ```
> def get_template_names(self):
>     """
>     Return a list of template names to be used for the request. Must return
>     a list. May not be called if render_to_response() is overridden.
>     """
>     if self.template_name is None:
>         raise ImproperlyConfigured(
>             "TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of "
>             "'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'")
>     else:
>         return [self.template_name]
> ```